# Query about Quad Boot system

Tags: boot, kali-linux, dual-boot

I have triple boot system with win7, ubuntu 13.10 and fedora 20 installed.How to quad boot with kali linux ? my hard disk is 750gb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install Kali Linux
- Do not install bootloader from Kali linux
- Boot into ubuntu
- Run grub-mkconfig
- Reboot and have fun